# SharePoint Sites "page not displayed" in Server working fine in workstation

Tags: 2013, site, iis7, logs

We recently applied Windows Server service pack in our QA farm. After-reboot i no longer can browse nay sites from Server themselves, but when i hit that web URL from my workstation they work fine.

Where do i start with this issue:

Troubleshooting steps i performed:

checked services: Working as expected.

Application pool: Started

IIS Sites: Started

Virtual Directory: Contains all files

Disable loopback  check: set to 1

checked  httperr files under windows\system32\logfiles: Connection looks good.

SharePoint Log is throwing :

> Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 11/17/2014 10:44:40.17, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.0516825462454027 for Data Source=SQL;Initial Catalog=SharePoint_AdminContent_d0f8c674-b1ef-4990-b002-21688ce9517d;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15;Application Name=SharePoint[w3wp][14][SharePoint_AdminContent_d0f8c674-b1ef-4990-b002-21688ce9517d]

Checked with SQl team, no issues in logs and all db's are healthy

Service Account Lockout status: Unlocked

Service account permission in db: Looks good.

Ran  a Fiddler on the server, got following response.

```
fiddler.network.https> Failed to secure existing connection for cadmininternal.xyz.com. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

Is there anything i can do?

Comment: Correlation ID: 06e4e29e-200f-304a-a16a-460213a636a5 Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 06/09/2019 10:47:43.24, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.0481948356556104 for Data Source=KVMSPSQLDEV01;Initial Catalog=DevSP_CBO_B2BPortal_Publishing;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Asynchronous Processing=False;Connection Reset=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Replication=False;Connect Timeout=50000;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Load Balance Timeout=0;Packet Size=8000;Type System Version=Latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed the issue, it ended up being the security patch that was installed into our server.

MS14-066: Vulnerability in SChannel could allow remote code execution: November 11, 2014

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2992611

After i uninstalled that KB it started working.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i confirmed with Windows Server team that it was security patching not the service pack install. Also I am using IE 8, Another interesting thing i found out today. Sites are working fine in one of the WFE but not in others. I have 2 wfe and 2 Application server. WFE 1 is working all nice but rest of the WFE and App server are having issues. I checked all the configs, they are all similar.

Some more info on side, one of the SQL cluster for backend sharepoint db was also affected by security patching upon reboot we had some issues, so we were finally able to start the SQL server with last best known config. Then we ran Windows server health check, things came out clean, also SQL team did the helath check no issues there either.

I am not getting why 1 wfe is working and rest are not, but when i access site from my work station everything looks good.

Additionally this is what i found in Httperr log this morning, does this ring any bells.

2014-11-19 02:43:05 (ip) 60061 (ip) 32843 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
 2014-11-19 14:11:55 (ip) 56646 (ip) 443 HTTP/1.0 GET / 404 - NotFound -
 2014-11-19 14:12:28 (ip) 56655 (ip) 443 HTTP/1.0 GET / 404 - NotFound -
 2014-11-19 14:31:12 127.0.0.1 56956 127.0.0.1 32844 HTTP/1.1 GET / 503 2 N/A SharePoint+Web+Services+Root
 2014-11-19 14:31:13 127.0.0.1 56957 127.0.0.1 32844 HTTP/1.1 GET /favicon.ico 503 2 N/A SharePoint+Web+Services+Root